# Hi ,I just bought an asus F55A but i can not enter bios?

Tags: boot, usb, asus, bios

Hi everybody I just bought an Asus F55A but I can not enter in bios or boot the linux usb before startup as i did before with my old asus k50c by pressing F2 for entering bios and CTRL+ESC+F1 to choose what to boot first the usb or the hard drive,can somebody help me please ????

Comment: You should look in the documentation that came with your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual does not state how to enter BIOS setup.  No doubt they expect you to be able to read the instructions when it flashes up on the screen momentarily.  It turns out the key to enter BIOS is <kbd>Del</kbd>.   The key to enter the boot menu (very hand to know) is just <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  Both of these are very common keys for Asus machines.

Comment: thanks man :))) ,it was simply esc as you said without ctrl and f1